# Where is the SSL certificate configuration in Ubuntu 18.04 - when it's not in the default location?

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, ssl

I set up a server with SSL config from THAWTE a few years ago. Preface, I have no idea what I am doing and managed with online tutorials. But somehow it works!

I need to update the SSL certificates to new ones, but can't remember at all what I did. So I followed more tutorials and found that my config should be in /etc/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf (There is also a 000-default but this file doesn't contain much)

Indeed there is a file in there that looks like I tampered with it with locations to my key, certificate, and intermediates. I went ahead and updated the files with my new certificate files, restarted the server, but it's still picking up the old certificate.

I can only guess there must be some other way to set up the SSL config. Is there a way to see what the current active config is, or where the files that are being used at the moment it located?

Appreciate any pointers, I'm stumped after cd-ing, ls-ing and vi-ing around for the last 3 hours.

Comment: How did you confirm that it is picking up the old certs?  Browsers are renowned for caching stale certs.  Try with `openssl s_client` or `curl` maybe, then update your question with the relevant info.

Comment: Hi Gareth, 

I checked with various online tools that check the certificate. They all reported the old certificate. 6 Hours later, that is still the case. 

Openssl returns 
`139720768586176:error:0200206F:system library:connect:Connection refused:../cryp                                              to/bio/b_sock2.c:110:
139720768586176:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/                                              bio/b_sock2.c:111:
`

Comment: You've not stated which web server you're using.  You can confirm with `netstat` or `ss`.  Both should take the options `-tlnp` if ran as root to list TCP listening ports - confirm what's running on port 443.  You can then do some more cd-ing to the relevant dir in `/etc` and look in those.  You're on the right track, but haven't found the offending file yet, or haven't restarted the service.  There is no central certificate store such as Windows'.

Comment: In the title stated Ubuntu 18.04 :)
Or do you mean apache?

The netstat command gave me (removed some lines for brevity

LISTEN       0             80                        127.0.0.1:3306                      0.0.0.0:*
LISTEN       0             100                            [::]:25                           [::]:*
LISTEN       0             128                               *:443                             *:*
LISTEN       0             128                               *:80                              *:*